# Compare with a value that is outside the sequence

Tags: c++, arrays

What happens if you compare a value (that belongs
to an array) with another value that does not belong to the same array (it is outside the sequence)

```
char arr[] = "yo";
strchr(arr + 3, '\r')
```

Can this ever crash a program? Or does it just compare to a char that is somewhere else?

Comment: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arr` if of type `char[3]`.

`arr + 3` is a pointer pointing to 1 past the last element of the array. It is legal to obtain a pointer to 1 past the last element of the array, but it is Undefined Behavior to dereference it.

`strchr` expects the first argument to be a pointer to a null terminated C string. Passing the above pointer here results in Undefined Behavior.

Comment: "It is legal to obtain a pointer to 1 past the last element of the array, but it is Undefined Behavior to dereference it." Does this mean I can for example compare/check using the address of last + 1, but not the value of it?

Comment: you can compare pointers that point within the same array (or 1 past the last element of the array). So you can do `arr + 1 < arr + 3`. And no, you cannot get the value pointed by `arr + 3` because there is no value there. Attempting to do so will result in UB.

Comment: Lastly, you said this was not legal: arr + 1 < arr + **4**... UB?

Comment: `arr + 4` is UB